# How to calculate co-ordinates after deformation

Tags: geometry

I am working in Objective-C which allows me to deform an image by pushing/pulling a single corner.  This allows me to take this image:

[image: Fig 1]

And deform it so that line AB is horizontal (points A & B have same y-value) thusly:

[image: Fig 2]

Notice how the deformation causes BOTH points A & B to be moved.  Now that they have moved, I want to know their new y-values.

My attempt has been:

[image: Fig 3]

```
1) Find angle E in triangle DEF
2) Use that to find angle D in triangle HDG
3) Use DG / sin(E) = HG / sin(D)
HG = (DF / sin(E)) * sin(D)
```

to solve for HG, which would give me the distance from the original y-coordinate for point A.

But these results are not correct.  What is the correct method?

Comment: If my answer below is correct, you might want to add the tag for projective geometry.

Comment: How do you find the point $E$? Where do you get the length $DG$ from?

Comment: @MvG: I will review your answer at length, but to respond to your comment; I know point E because that is a value I calculate and then feed to the image filter which does the deformation.  I also know the length and position of line DF because that is the original image boundary.

Comment: Edit: point G is point A's original position.

Comment: In the illustrations you gave, $G$ is clearly *not* at $A$'s original location: $A$ is closer to the center of its edge than $G$ is to that of $DF$. If you incorrectly assumed the original location to be the orthogonal projection of the deformed position, then that is likely the cause why your computations fail. I wonder how you computed $E$ to meet your requirements without the method I used. If you managed to obtain an equivalent solution using a different approach, perhaps that approach can be adjusted to provide an answer which is closer to your way of thinking.

Comment: @MvG: Yes, I have incorrectly assumed the original location to be the orthogonal projection of the deformed position, thank you for the clarity on that.

Comment: @MvG: My method for finding E: find the difference of Ay and By, and multiply that by difference of Bx and the length of the right-hand side.  If A = left-hand corner of the figure, then this (distance + Ay) would be E, and the deformation (moving the left-hand corner upwards) would bring Ay == By.  But A is not reliably in the left-hand corner.  So I calculate the angle at A of triangle E - A - (Bx,Ay), and also find angle E.  I then use E = (length of top side) / sin(E) * sin(A) to find final E.  I use the iOS image filters to deform the left-hand corner with consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

## General approach

Your deformation looks like a projective transformation. Since projective transformations preserve neither angles nor lengths nor even length ratios, your attempts using elementary trigonometry are probably bound to fail. A projective transformation in the plane is uniquely defined by four points and their images, as long as no three points lie on a common line. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) gives details on how you can compute such a transformation.

Note that if you already know the coordinates of the “pulled” rectangle corner ($E$ in your question), then you can simply use your four corners as the four defining points. Since finding the correct position for $E$ is non-trivial, I didn't make that assumption. So the main task here is finding four suitable pairs of points. You can use the resulting machinery not only without prior knowledge of $E$, but in fact even as a tool to compute $E$ in the first place.

## Coordinates for four defining points

Suppose your original rectangle has width $w$ and height $h$. Then you can assume the following homogenous coordinates. I'll place the origin of the coordinate system in the lower left corner of your rectangle, and the positive $y$ axis pointing upwards. If you use a different convention, these coordinates should be easy to adapt.

\begin{align*}
P_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
P_2 &= \begin{pmatrix}w\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
P_3 &= \begin{pmatrix}w\\h\\1\end{pmatrix} &
P_4 &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\h\\1\end{pmatrix} \\
A &= \begin{pmatrix}a\\h\\1\end{pmatrix} &
B &= \begin{pmatrix}w\\b\\1\end{pmatrix} &
H &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} &
V &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} &
\end{align*}

The points $P_i$ are the corners of your rectangle, $A$ and $B$ are as in your images, while $H$ and $V$ are the points at infinity through which all horizontal resp. vertical lines must pass. Now we need some additional points. Using homogenous coordinates, you can use the cross product to express both the line joining two points and the point at the intersection oftwo lines. So the line $AB$ will intersect the bottom line of your rectangle in a point

$$Q = (A\times B)\times(P_1\times P_2)$$

Now you can define your transformation using the following:

\begin{align*}
P_1 &\mapsto P_1 \\
P_2 &\mapsto P_2 \\
P_4 &\mapsto P_4 \\
V &\mapsto V \\
Q &\mapsto H
\end{align*}

So three corners remain where they are, vertical lines remain vertical, and the two lines intersecting at $Q$ will both become horizontal. These are five points, not four, but some of them are collinear. So I'd keep the first three conditions, and use some point constructed from several of these defining points as the fourth condition:

$$ (P_2\times V)\times(P_4\times Q) \mapsto
(P_2\times V)\times(P_4\times H) $$

This gives you a fourth defining pair of points which (barring degenerate situations) does not lie on the same line as two of the other defining points. So now you have four pairs of preimage and image points, and can [compute the transformation matrix from these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416).

## Using the transformation

Applying that transformation matrix to $A$ or $B$ (and perhaps $P_3$) will give you their new coordinates, which you'll probably want to dehomogenize. But these steps are also described in [my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416).

## Explicit result

All of the above computations could be done symbolically using some computer algebra system. the resulting expressions aren't that bad. The $y$ coordinate of $E=P_3'$ is

$$E_y = \frac{a\,b\,h-w\,h^2}{a\,b-b\,w}$$

and the $y$ coordinate of the transformed line $AB$ is

$$H_y = \frac{a\,b-h\,w}{a-w}$$

So if you only need these, but need them in a number of situations, then you might simply want to implement this final formula. Understanding the whole process used to obtain these will however be useful in dealing with other, similar situations.

## Sage code

I obtained the above formulas using the following piece of [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) code:

```
def joinMeet(a, b, c, d):
    return a.cross_product(b).cross_product(c.cross_product(d))
def pm1(a, b, c, d):
    M = Matrix([a , b, c]).transpose()
    f = M.solve_right(d)
    return M*diagonal_matrix(f)
def pm(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2):
    return pm1(a2, b2, c2, d2)*(pm1(a1, b1, c1, d1).adjoint())
def dehom(p):
    return vector([p[0]/p[2], p[1]/p[2]])
var('w h a b')
P1 = vector([0, 0, 1])
P2 = vector([w, 0, 1])
P3 = vector([w, h, 1])
P4 = vector([0, h, 1])
A = vector([a, h, 1])
B = vector([w, b, 1])
H = vector([1, 0, 0])
V = vector([0, 1, 0])
Q = joinMeet(A, B, P1, P2)
R1 = joinMeet(P2, V, P4, Q)
R2 = joinMeet(P2, V, P4, H)
M = pm(P1, P1, P2, P2, P4, P4, R1, R2)
print(dehom(M*P3)[1].simplify_full())
print(dehom(M*A)[1].simplify_full())
```