# Smooth conics in complex projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

How can I show that each smooth conic in $\Bbb P _2\Bbb C $ is  isomorph to the conic given by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$?
I thought about considering the quadratic form $A$ associated to my conic, A is symmetric so I can say that $D=P^{-1}AP$ where D is diagonal with coefficients $d_1, d_2, d_3$. Know I probably have to define a maps from $\Bbb P _2\Bbb C $ to $\Bbb P _2\Bbb C $ using $P$, but I can't understand which is the correct way to do that!
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2613755)

Comment: @JeanMarie isn't it possible to go on from my reasoning? Here is quite different...

Comment: A small suggestion. Go the other way. Start with the conic $\,x^2+y^2+z^2=0\,$ and use any invertable linear map on $\,\mathbb{C}^3\,$ (which also induces a map $\,P_2\mathbb{C}\to P_2\mathbb{C}$) and apply it to the conic.