# Homography in projective spaces

Tags: projective-geometry

In $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^3$ the following quadric are given:

$Q_1: x_0^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=0$, $Q_2: x_0^2+x_1^2-x_2^2-2x_0x_3+2x_2x_3=0.$

Say if there is a homography $\omega: \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\omega(Q_1) =Q_2$.

Comment: Hello, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654275/homography-between-ellipses