# Linear Transformation of points

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Could you help me solve this: For projective coordinate system on the line $l$ are given points $A (2,1)$, $B (1,1)$, $C (0,1)$, $A_1 (0,1)$, $B_1 (1,5)$ and $C_1 (2,1 )$. Find a linear transformation where the points $A, B$ and $C$ go respectively at  $A_1$, $B_1$, and $C_1$.

I tryed to solve it but I dont know what to do.

Here is what I tryed: 
\begin{equation}
ρ_1 * \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}m & n \\ p & q \\ \end{pmatrix}* \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
ρ_2 * \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}m & n \\ p & q \\ \end{pmatrix}* \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
ρ_3 * \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}m & n \\ p & q \\ \end{pmatrix}* \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

2m + n = 0
2p + q = $ρ_1$

m + n = $ρ_2$
p + q = 5*$ρ_2$

n = 2*$ρ_3$
q = $ρ_3$

Is that the right way ? I got some equations for **m, n, p, q** but I dont think they are right. What should I do now ?

Comment: What equations did you get? If you don't write them down how will anyone know whether you go wrong and where?

Comment: The factors $\rho_i$ indicate that you are in fact looking for a projective transformation, not a linear one. You can use the techniques from [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) but reduce the dimension by one: instead of for points defining a transformation of the projective plane, you have three points defining a transformation of the projective line.