# Rotate secondary vanishing points to the primary vanishing points to find new length of object

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

all though only the 2D data is available, the best way to think of this problem is a piece of paper pinned at one corner to a wall, but the paper is sitting at an angle to the wall, see illustration below, this generates a second set of vanishing points v2a and v2b. Given only this 2D data, I want to rotate the "paper" so it is parallel to the wall, which is easy enough to rotate, but point a1 stretches out to a new length d1-a2, this does not stretch proportionately with the length of v2b going to v1b, because it is in perspective (from a 3D world), it is instead some log proportion.

so this is the question, what is the calculation that is used to find the new length d1-a2? after a rotation as shown, given a known length d1-a1 (in a 2dimensional set up as shown).

I am not very good at reading scientific notation, so if the answer could also be expressed in "C" or objective-C code, (or even sudo code) that would be great.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that the answer lies in the intersection i1,

so that a good approximation of the length that i seek:

(d1-i1) * ((cos(a1) pow n)  =  d1-a2

where "n" is a ratio of ((v1a - v1b) / (v2b - v1a))

I'm still looking to improve this approximation.

the line (d1-i1) lies on the line (d1-v1b)

Update:  i've found several situations now where this doesn't work as an approximation, so I am still looking for a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this question is resemblant to:

- [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript)

There are few good answers at that place. If I'm not mistaken ..

Comment: that question/answer is on the right track,  but I believe the question and answer depend on the knowledge that you know both the four source points,  and also the four destination points, and you are then just using a matrix to map the start image,  to the final image.   In my question,  I really don't know the four destination points ahead of time,  that is what I am trying to find,  (but then I would use a similar approach after finding these points.)

Comment: @hokkuk: If you specify exactly what is _known_ and what is _unknown_, that would help.

Comment: what is known is the length d1-a1,  what I would like to find is the length d1-a2.

Comment: @hokkuk: Okay, but how about c1,c2,b1,b2 ?

Comment: if the length d1-a2 can be found,  all the rest can be found in a similar manner as to what ever the method that was used to find d1-a2.