# Special cubics that are determined by 6 or 7 points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

In the case of quadratic curves it is widely known that a conic is uniquely determined by 5 points. But if we use only three points we can uniquely determine a circle and if four points -- a parabola. Both are special curves in some sense (the first one is special in Euclidean geometry and the other one is special in Affine/Projective geometry).

The question is probably a little bit vague, but what special types of cubics can be determined by just 6 or 7 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle is a conic through the two ideal circle points $[1:\pm i:0]$, so this is just another case of a conic through five points, with two chosen in a special way. You could simply generalize this to cubics by taking these ideal circle points as points on the cubic as well. Since they play a very central part in modelling Euclidean geometry in the projective plane, the result will likely have interesting Euclidean properties as well, but I don't know which.

A parabola is a conic tangent to the line at infinity. So if you want to define a parabola by four points, you are in a special case of the more generic problem of finding a conic given four points and one tangent line. Which has *two* solutions in general, and even in your specific situation.

[image: Two parabolas through four given points]

If you want things to be uniquely determined, you should define a parabola by four tangent lines. This you can again generalize to the cubic case, by taking the line at infinity and 7 more tangents. Or you stick with 7 points and one tangent line at infinity, and accept that the results are no longer unique.

Comment: As a side note: if you are interested in mixed definitions, i.e. defining conics by incident points and tangent lines, have a look at [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122145/35416) about three points and two lines defining four conics.