# Find a projective transformation that sends the locus $x^2-y^2=z^2 $ to $yz=x^2$

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

So I'm trying to find a function that sends  $x^2-y^2=z^2$ to $yz=x^2$. I know it can be done because all conics are projectively equivalent. I think I have to use a matrix of some kind but I don't know how.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: $x^2-y^2=uv$ with $u=x-y$, $v=x+y$.

Answer (score 1):

In general you have three degrees of freedom when mapping one conic to another. One approach is the following: choose three distinct points $A,B,C$ resp. $A',B',C'$ on each conic. Then construct a point $D$ as follows: take the tangents to the first conic in $A$ and $B$, intersecting these in a point $P$ and join that point of intersection with $C$. That last line will intersect the conic in a second point, which is that point $D$. Do the same to construct $D'$ on the second conic. Now you can [compute the projective transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) which maps these four preimages to their corresponding images.

Applied to your situation, where you can use *any* matching transformation, you could choose simple coordinates on each conic. E.g.

\begin{align*}
&& M &= \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix} &
&& M' &= \begin{pmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
MA &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
A' &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} &
M'A' &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} \\
B &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix} &
MB &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
B' &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} &
M'B' &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} \\
C &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} &
P &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} &
C' &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} &
P' &= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
D &= (P^TMP)C-(2C^TMP)P &
D' &= (P'^TM'P')C'-(2C'^TM'P')P'
\\
D &= -C+2P = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} &
D' &= -2C'+4P' \sim \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

If you now follow the steps from [my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) you will find that the projective transformation which maps $A,B,C,D$ to $A',B',C',D'$ can be described by the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Of course, this is ony *one* suitable transformation from the three-parameter family of possible transformations.