# Finding the transformation matrix of a projective transformation in RP^2

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry, transformation, projective-geometry, projective-space

So I want to understand how to find the matrix that represents the projective transformation that sends 4 given points to 4 given images, I know that 4 points are necessary to determine it but I can't quite understand how to find it.

I did see this [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript)

but my question is not the same, because I am not given four points in R^2, ie, (x,y), I'm given four points in RP^2, ie, [x,y,z].

In particular, I'm given the basis [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] and [1,1,1] and the images [1,0,0], [1,2,0], [1,2,3] and [4,5,6], but I'm more interested in understanding the general method.