# Calculating point coordinates from a perspective

Tags: geometry

I’m designing a 3d game and am having trouble computing where the mouse pointer is actually pointing on the flat map when taking into account perspective which skews the view.

[image: Rendered image showing surfaces and lines described below]

Let’s assume that the flat plane is part of the map, and the tilted plane is the viewport. Player’s camera is rotated arbitrarily but always pointing up, and has a defined position $C$. Cyan line crosses both $C$ and $O$, so cyan vector $\vec{d}=\overline{CO}$ is known.

Orange line is parallel to cyan line, and were all objects rotated and translated so that skewed surface becomes $z=0$ and $C$ becomes $(0, 0, 0)$, then the point of intersection $M$ between orange line and skewed surface would become $(x,y,0)$.

I know that, if the system was translated and rotated like so, the point I’m looking for would be somewhere on the line $\overline{CM}$ between $C$ and $M$, but can’t figure out exactly where.

How do I get the point of intersection between the flat surface and the orange vector?

Comment: Perhasp [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

Point $C$ is the location of the camera, it is looking at $(0, 0, 0)$. That means that we have cyan vector $\vec{d}=(-M_x,-M_y,-M_z)$. Length of $\vec{d}$ is $l=\sqrt{M_x^2+M_y^2+M_z^2}$.

We now define $\vec{d'}=\frac{\vec{d}}{l}$ in order to get a vector with $|\vec{d'}|=1$.

We introduce vector $\vec{u}$ as $\vec{u}=(0, 0, 1)$. This is generalisation, as it determines which direction is up relative to the camera's view. In my case, I use $(0, 0, 1)$, because that's hardcoded in my game.

Again, for generalisation purposes, we define $\vec{u'}=\frac{\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}$.

We'll need one more vector, $\vec{v}=\vec{u'}\times\vec{d'}$.

Now, what the camera sees depends on the field of view. We know the angle which the camera sees, let's call it $\varphi$. Then, $t_{FOV}=\tan{\frac{\varphi}{2}}$.

We create new vectors $\vec{u''}=\vec{u'}t_{FOV}$ and $\vec{v''}=\vec{v'}t_{FOV}$.

We know the point of intersection of orange vector and skewed plane is $M$ which is really the point on the screen we see, and we know the size of the screen is $(w,h)$. The coordinate lies somewhere on this vector:

$$\vec{m}_x=\vec{d}_x+\vec{u}_x(1-\frac{2M_y}{h})+\vec{v}_x(\frac{2M_x}{w}-1)$$
$$\vec{m}_y=\vec{d}_y+\vec{u}_y(1-\frac{2M_y}{h})+\vec{v}_y(\frac{2M_x}{w}-1)$$
$$\vec{m}_z=\vec{d}_z+\vec{u}_z(1-\frac{2M_y}{h})+\vec{v}_z(\frac{2M_x}{w}-1)$$

Now we define $\vec{m''}=\frac{\vec{m'}}{|\vec{m'}|}$ and $\lambda=-\frac{\vec{d}_Z}{\vec{m''}_z}$

Finally, The point we are looking for is

$$(-\vec{d}_x-\vec{m''}_x\lambda, -\vec{d}_y-\vec{m''}_y\lambda)$$