# Calculating transformation matrix for perspective transform

Tags: analytic-geometry, transformation, geometric-transformation

I'm using the getPerspectiveTransform() method of OpenCV (description [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform)). This method calculates a perspective transform from four pairs of the corresponding points. So we have to specify four start (source) points and 4 end (destination) points.

Let's assume we have the 4 start points $p_{s1}=(x_{s1}, y_{s1})$, $p_{s2}=(x_{s2}, y_{s2})$, $p_{s3}=(x_{s3}, y_{s3})$, $p_{s4}=(x_{s4}, y_{s4})$ and the 4 end points  $p_{e1}=(x_{e1}, y_{e1})$, $p_{e2}=(x_{e2}, y_{e2})$, $p_{e3}=(x_{e3}, y_{e3})$, $p_{e4}=(x_{e4}, y_{e4})$. (The points can also be named differently, I don't know if I chose the best naming).

How is the $3\times3$ transformation matrix calculated from the 4 start and end points?

Comment: If all else fails, you can check out the implementation in the python library source file.

Comment: @Berci Yes, but it is somewhat hard to come up with a concise mathematical formulation from the source code.

Comment: If you want what the code is doing specifically, you’re going to have to find some implementation documentation or reverse-engineer it yourself. However, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/265466) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680520/265466) for various methods.