# Mapping image's 4 corners to warped 4 corners...

Tags: image-processing

I need to write a script for an illustration program which will take an
image, allow the user to outline the rectangular face within the image, and
then warp the image so that the rectangular face is actually rectangular to
the viewing plane. See the image below.  I do not need to do the actual
mapping, the program will do that for me if I give it a new rectangle to
'fit' the image to.

Given the set of image corner coordinates *(A, B, C and D)* and a set
of coordinates within the image *(E, F, G and H)*, how do I determine the
coordinates of the final transformed image *(I, J, K and L)*?

As far as which rectangle to map E-H to in order to get I-L, let's call those *M, N, O, and P*. They will be known.

I am only looking for help with the mathematics of the transformations. I can handle the programming part once I understand the maths.

[image: Visual Explanation]

Comment: did you try the computer science stack exchange.

Comment: I just need the mathematics involved. I can write the program once I understand the maths.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/265466. You want the inverse of the transformation constructed there.

Comment: These equations might help you: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/krm1owqa5b