# calculating dividing lines of a quadrangle, with perspective.

Tags: geometry

I am writing a simple piece of software to draw a grid on top of a quadrangle (e.g. 3D depiction of a chess board).

A chess board consist of 8x8 squares or 9x9 lines. So, basically it's a square with 7 dividing lines in each direction (horizontal and vertical).

[image: perspective]

If I look down on the board from the top, it will be a square.
When I look at it from the side of the table (sitting on a chair) it will be almost like a trapezium.
However, when I look at it from any other angle, **it will just be a quadrangle.**

Let's say I take the picture of a square (which is a 2D figure in a 3D space), the result will be a new 2D figure in my flat picture (which is a 2D space).

The challenge is to draw the 7 lines on top of this quadrangle. Of course it's not just a matter of dividing the length of each side by 7, because there is a 3D perspective that needs to be taken in account.

I will use this for a computer program.
So, I am actually taking a picture of a grid with a smart phone., and I want to create an "augmented reality" by drawing the dividing lines on top of the quadrangle.

So, basically I'm looking for the maths to solve this problem:

- the **input** of my algorithm are the **projected 2D coordinates of the 4 corners**.
- the **output** are the **start-stop coordinates of the 7 lines.**
- it should be an algorithm that works for any number of lines. (e.g. dividing by 17 lines)

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How is the image of the chess board generated in the first place?

Comment: @amd by taking a picture with a smartphone. the coordinates of the 4 corners are next provided by a neural network.

Comment: There are couple of reasonably simple ways to attack this, then. You could compute the homography that maps the square chess board to the quad in the image. This is a library function in many graphics APIs, or you can use the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/265466). This will let you map *any* point in the plane of the chess board to the image. Alternatively, you can compute the vanishing points of the edges and use cross-ratios to compute the grid end points. I’ll write this up in more detail when I get some more time.

Comment: @amd what I did try, was to calculate the position of the 2 vanishing points, and their angle. Next I divided those 2 angles, each in 7 parts and for each vanishing point, I drew 6 lines (using those angles) through the original quad, creating a grid. At first looked like a great solution. But unfortunately it's not correct at all.

Comment: That’s a good start, but the angular spacing you need is non-uniform, as you’ve seen.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to compute the homography (planar perspective transformation) that maps the square board onto the detected quadrangle in the image, then use that transformation to map grid line endpoints onto the image. There are some advantages to this method. First, this computation is available as a library function in many graphics APIs, so you can do it with basically no work on your part. Second, it allows you to map *any* point in the plane of the board onto the image, which can be handy depending on what else you’re going to be doing. Third, it might allow you to blast the grid out as a texture with suitable alpha for transparency. If this function isn’t available in the APIs that you’re using, you can do this computation yourself. You can find a description of the process [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript/339033#339033). For this application, computing the homography is particularly simple: you can use the unit square for the board, in which case you don’t have to compute a second intermediate matrix when using the linked method—the homography is simply $A^{-1}$.

Since you’ve computed the vanishing points of the board edges, another way to go is to use cross-ratios to compute the grid line endpoints: if $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are distinct colinear points, then the ratio $$(A,B;C,D) = {AC \cdot BD \over AB \cdot CD}$$ is invariant under projective transformations. If you have three fixed pairs of corresponding points on a line and its image, you can use the equality of the cross-ratios to find the image of any other point on the line.

For each of the edges you’ve got the images of the endpoints $P_1$ and $P_2$ and can compute the vanishing point $P_\infty$, which gives the necessary three pairs. The latter is the image of a point at infinity in the overhead view of the board, which presents a slight difficulty as its distance from any of the other points on the line is infinite, but that can be dealt with by introducing homogeneous coordinates on the line and using determinants of pairs of points. Taking the unit square as the original chess board, we have $\mathbf 0=[0:1]$, $\mathbf 1=[1:1]$, $\mathbf\infty=[1:0]$ and $\mathbf\lambda=[\lambda:1]$, with cross-ratio $$(\mathbf 0,\mathbf\lambda;\mathbf 1,\mathbf\infty) = {\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \cdot \begin{vmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} \over \begin{vmatrix} 0 & \lambda \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \cdot \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}} = {(-1)\cdot(-1) \over (-\lambda)\cdot(-1)} = \frac1\lambda.$$ On the image side of things, we have the endpoints $P_0=[x_0:y_0:1]$, $P_1=[x_1:y_1:1]$ and the vanishing point $P_\infty=[x_\infty:y_\infty:1]$ (I’m assuming for now that the vanishing point is finite). We want the value of $\mu$ for which $P_\mu = (1-\mu)P_0+\mu P_1$ is the image of $\mathbf\lambda$, that is, for which $(P_0,P_\mu;P_1,P_\infty)=(\mathbf 0,\mathbf\lambda;\mathbf 1,\mathbf\infty)$. We can compute distances between these various image points and then get the cross-ratio, but it can also be computed by choosing a point not on the line and using determinants of $3\times3$ matrices formed from various combinations of the points. A convenient choice is the origin $O=[0:0:1]$, because the determinants then become wedge products of the Cartesian coordinates of pairs of points. (If the linear extension of the edge happens to pass through the origin, just translate the points so that it doesn’t.) The cross-ratio of the image points is then $$(P_0,P_\mu;P_1,P_\infty) = {[O,P_0,P_1]\cdot[O,P_\mu,P_\infty] \over [O,P_0,P_\mu]\cdot[O,P_1,P_\infty]} = {(x_0y_1-y_0x_1) \left((1-\mu) (x_0y_\infty-y_0x_\infty)+\mu (x_1y_\infty-y_1x_\infty)\right) \over \mu (x_0y_1-y_0x_1) (x_1y_\infty-y_1x_\infty)}.$$ Setting the two cross-ratios equal to each other and solving for $\mu$ produces $$\mu = {\lambda (x_0y_\infty-y_0x_\infty) \over (1-\lambda) (x_1y_\infty - y_1x_\infty) + \lambda (x_0y_\infty - y_0x_\infty)}.$$ This is an instance of a linear fractional transformation. Note that even though the cross ratio is undefined for $\lambda=0$, this formula produces $\mu=0$, as we’d like.

If a pair of edges is parallel, or nearly so, with the vanishing point far away from the image of the board, then you can just subdivide them evenly instead of going through the above mapping. (In this case, $P_\infty=[x_1-x_0:y_1-y_0:0]$, and if you work through the cross-ratio computation, you end up with $1/\mu$, i.e., $\mu=\lambda$.)