# Projectivity on a line and harmonic groups

Tags: projective-geometry

On a projective line, we have pairwise distinct points $A,B,U,P,O,A',B',Q$ such that the following groups are harmonic:

- $ABUO$;
- $APUA'$;
- $BPUB'$;
- $A'B'PQ$.

Let consider the following projectivities:
$$\Lambda:\begin{pmatrix}A&B&O\\A'&B'&O\end{pmatrix}\qquad\Theta:\begin{pmatrix}A&B&P\\A'&B'&P\end{pmatrix}$$

> Question: prove that $\Lambda(P)=\Theta(O)$ and
>   $\Lambda^{-1}(U)=\Theta^{-1}(Q)$.

I proved that $\Lambda(Q)=Q$, $\Theta(U)=U$ and that there exists an involution $H$ such that
$$H:\begin{pmatrix}A&B&P&Q\\B'&A'&U&O\end{pmatrix}$$

Moreover I proved that for a point $P'$ the following conditions are equivalent: $P'=\Theta(O)$, $OPUP'$ is harmonic, $A'B'UP'$ is harmonic.
It's enough to show $P'=\Lambda(P)$, but I cannot find a way to prove it.

Comment: What does mean that ABUO are harmonic?

Comment: Is that line real

Comment: I means that O is the [harmonic conjugate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) of U respect to AB.

Comment: You can take a real line, but I think is valid on any field of characteristic distict from 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of more clever ideas, I like using coordinates. Without loss of generality you can pick three points as a projective basis on the line. This will reduce the number of variables somewhat. Pretty much at random I did pick

$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\qquad
U=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Pick one coordinate for one of the other points:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}p\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

The rest can be derived from these. A harmonic throw has cross-ratio $-1$. Writing $[\cdot,\cdot]$ for a $2\times2$ determinant the harmonic throw $APUA'$ translates into

\begin{align*}
-1=(A,P;U,A')&=\frac{[A,U][P,A']}{[A,A'][P,U]}\\
-[A,A'][P,U]&=[A,U][P,A']\\
0&=[A,U][P,A']+[A,A'][P,U]\\
0&=[A,[P,A']U+[P,U]A']\\
A&\sim[P,A']U+[P,U]A'\\
A&\sim\begin{vmatrix}p&1\\1&0\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}p&1\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
A&=\begin{pmatrix}2-p\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Of course you could have taken any other representative, but this one is particularly convenient. In the same fashion from $(B,P;U,B')=-1$ you get

$$[P,B']U+[P,U]B'=
\begin{vmatrix}p&0\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}p&1\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}p\\2p-1\end{pmatrix}=B$$

And from $(A',B';P,Q)=-1$ you get

$$[P,A']B'+[P,B']A'=
\begin{vmatrix}p&1\\1&0\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}p&0\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}-p\\1\end{pmatrix}=Q$$

Finally from $(A,B;U,O)=-1$ you get (simplified by cancelling a factor of $2p-2$)

$$[U,A]B+[U,B]A=
\begin{vmatrix}1&2-p\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p\\2p-1\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}1&p\\1&2p-1\end{vmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2-p\\1\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}1\\p\end{pmatrix}=O$$

Given these points, you can formulate the transformation matrices explicitly using [this computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416).

$$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}1-2p&p\\p&p^2-2p\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\Theta=\begin{pmatrix}2p-1&-p\\1&p-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now it's a matter of doing the multiplications to confirm that

$$[\Lambda P,\Theta O]=0$$

i.e. the determinant is zero as the vectors are scalar multiples of one another. For the inverse operations, you can use the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), as this matches the inverse up to some factor.

$$\operatorname{adj}\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}p^2-2p&-p\\-p&1-2p\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\operatorname{adj}\Theta=\begin{pmatrix}p-2&p\\-1&2p-1\end{pmatrix}$$

With these you can check the second half of the claim in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\send}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\\#2\end{pmatrix}}$
Starting from MvG answer, I get the following coordinate-free solution to the problem.

Let $P'$ making $OPUP'$ harmonic.
Since $OPUP'$, $APUA'$ and $BPUB'$ are harmonic, they are projective, hence
\begin{align*}
\send{A&P&U&A'}{O&P&U&P'}&
\iff\send{A&P&U&O}{A'&P&U&P'}&
\send{B&P&U&B'}{O&P&U&P'}&
\iff\send{B&P&U&O}{B'&P&U&P'}
\end{align*}
Comparing them, we get $\Theta:\send{A&B&P&U&O}{A'&B'&P&U&P'}$.
Since $ABUO$ is harmonic, the group $A'B'UP'$ is harmonic as well.
Then $OPUP'$ and $A'B'UP'$ are both harmonic, thus we get an involution $\send{A'&B'&P&P'}{B'&A'&O&P'}$.
By double switching, we get $\send{A'&B'&P&P'}{A'&B'&P'&O}$.
Composing with $\Theta$ gives $\Lambda:\send{A&B&O&P}{A'&B'&O&P'}$ which proves $\Lambda(P)=P'=\Theta(O)$.