# Deskew and rotate a photographed rectangular image (aka "perspective correction")

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, rectangles

I photographed a rectangular shape, but:

- the camera angle is not perfect
- the image is possibly rotated.

Given the coordinates of 8 points $ A_1 (x_1, y_1), ..., A_8 (x_8, y_8)$, how to transform the input coordinates into perfectly rectangular output coordinates?

[image]

Note:

1) Additional information: the deskewed rectangle has a width $W = 21\ cm$ and a height $H = 29.7\ cm$. Also $A_1 A_2 A_4 A_3$ is a square of 1 cm x 1 cm, and $A_5 A_6 A_8 A_7$ too.

2) The problem will probably have multiple solutions, up to rotations of 90 or 180 degrees

3) It's probably possible with only 6 points (or even less?) but I'd like to make use of all the 8 points to improve quality (it's an overdetermined problem, so using least-squares could probably help, but I don't know how to do it in this context)

Comment: Even if you fix the "target" rectangle of assigned height and width, the mapping is not unique because of the rotational symmetry of the rectangle, e.g. it could be rotated through an angle $\pi$ without change.

Comment: Already answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/1257

Comment: @brainjam it's related but not exactly the same (see my last remark in question)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had 8 source points.  Generally 4 is sufficient, along with 4 target points.  Since you are posing an overdetermined problem you probably want something like a least squares solution, like https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ea51/33a54d8134765d9479ae62b538e2813f5c3d.pdf  The problem is that you don't know what the target points would be that correspond to any of the source points other than $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_8,y_8)$.

Comment: @brainjam Yes, it's overdetermined and I was also thinking about least squares, but not sure how to do it in this context. See my updated Note 1 in the question for more informations: I do know the target points for all points $A_i$, for $i \in {1, 2, ..., 8}$.

Comment: To move forward you should justify whether using 8 points instead of 4 is really worth the significant extra effort.  And if you still think 8 points is a good idea you should explain where the existing least squares solutions literature is not helping.

Comment: @brainjam which 4 points? I only have points at the top left corner and points at the bottom right of the page, but no point at the top right for example.

Comment: I had assumed you could easily get the top right point.  But if not, any 4 of the 8 points should do. In fact, if you give me 4 points (and their targets) I can run them through WolframAlpha for you to get a transform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77828/discussion-between-basj-and-brainjam).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Only four points (like four corners of a sheet of paper) are enough to do the deskewing, the transform is known as a "homography" (as stated in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2789116/109021)).  See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2791887/109021) about these transformations. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation) is how to do it on an image with only a few lines of Python + OpenCV:

[image]

2) When we want to use **8 points** to do it, **the problem is overdetermined**, and we want to find the optimal solution by minimising an error (least-squares style). It's exactly what [`findHomography`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) from the library OpenCV does (see remarks there about minimization of error). Here is how to do it with Python + OpenCV:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('IMG_20180522_211242_2.jpg')
pts1 = np.float32([[58,642],[147,627],[83,733],[168,716],[2320,2654],[2291,2566],[2238,2675],[2211,2588]])
pts2 = np.float32([[50,50],[150,50],[50,150],[150,150],[2100-50, 2970-50],[2100-50,2970-150],[2100-150,2970-50],[2100-150,2970-150]])
size = (2100,2970)

M, mask = cv2.findHomography(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,size)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: I now realize this is a programming+math question/answer (if so, feel free to migrate it to StackOverflow), or maybe half math/half programming, and then another more math-oriented-answer is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

`QuadrilateralGrid[q_List, nx_, ny_] := 
 Module[{u, i, grf, graphics = {}},
  For[i = 1, i <= nx, i++, u = i/nx; 
   AppendTo[graphics, 
    ParametricPlot[(q[[1]] u + q[[2]] (1 - u)) v + (q[[4]] u + 
         q[[3]] (1 - u)) (1 - v), {v, 0, 1}]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= ny, i++, u = i/ny; 
   AppendTo[graphics, 
    ParametricPlot[(q[[2]] u + q[[3]] (1 - u)) v + (q[[1]] u + 
         q[[4]] (1 - u)) (1 - v), {v, 0, 1}]]];
  AppendTo[graphics, 
   ListLinePlot[{q[[1]], q[[2]], q[[3]], q[[4]], q[[1]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]];
  Return[graphics]
  ]`

`QuadrilateralCoords[q_List, p_List] := 
 Module[{coords = {}, i, x, y, sol, c0 = q[[3]], c1 = q[[4]] - q[[3]],
    c2 = q[[2]] - q[[3]], c3 = q[[1]] - q[[4]] - q[[2]] + q[[3]], s1, 
   s2, s0},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[p], i++,
   sol = Quiet[
     Solve[Thread[c0 + x c1 + y c2 + x y c3 == p[[i]]], {x, y}]];
   If[Length[sol] < 2, s0 = ({x, y} /. sol)[[1]],
    s1 = {x, y} /. sol[[1]];
    s2 = {x, y} /. sol[[2]];
    s0 = s2;
    If[s1[[1]] > 0 && s1[[1]] < 1 && s1[[2]] > 0 && s1[[2]] < 1, 
     s0 = s1]];
   AppendTo[coords, s0]
   ];
  Return[coords]
  ]`


`QuadrilateralPlotPoints[q_List, coords_] := 
 Module[{graphics = {}, nc = Length[coords], i, u, v, p1, p2, p0, , 
   diag1 = Norm[q[[1]] - q[[3]]], diag2 = Norm[q[[2]] - q[[4]]], diag,
    rad},
  diag = Max[diag1, diag2];
  rad = 0.008*diag;
  For[i = 1, i <= nc, i++,
   u = coords[[i, 1]];
   v = coords[[i, 2]];
   p1 = q[[1]] u + q[[2]] (1 - u);
   p2 = q[[4]] u + q[[3]] (1 - u);
   p0 = p1 v + p2 (1 - v);
   AppendTo[graphics, Graphics[{Red, Disk[p0, rad]}]]];
  AppendTo[graphics, 
   ListLinePlot[{q[[1]], q[[2]], q[[3]], q[[4]], q[[1]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]];
  Return[graphics]
  ]`


`quadrilateral = {{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 5}, {-3, 2}};
base = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 3}, {0, 3}};
Show[QuadrilateralGrid[quadrilateral, 10, 10], PlotRange -> All ]
Show[QuadrilateralGrid[base, 10, 10], PlotRange -> All ]`

[image]

[image]

`basepoints = 
  Table[{0.5 Cos[t] + 1, 0.5 Sin[t] + 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.3}];
coordsbase = QuadrilateralCoords[base, basepoints];
Show[QuadrilateralPlotPoints[quadrilateral, coordsbase]]
Show[QuadrilateralPlotPoints[base, coordsbase]]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does this assume it's a parallelogram? In real situation it's not, the opposite sides are not necessary parallel.

Comment: Not at all. The skewed figure can be distorted as a general quadrilateral.

Comment: $M$ copes for the scales at any axis and $R$ copes with the rotation and $p_0$ with an eventual origin translation.

Comment: Doesn't really address how to do the minimization or limit the space of M

Comment: Is a standard minimization procedure that can be handled easily with NMinimize in MATHEMATICA for instance.

Comment: See script attached.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute a projective transformation (aka homography, collineation).  Details at [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/1257)

If you want to pursue least squares methods you might find this Mathematica answer helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9244/solve-system-of-equations-related-to-perspective-projection

Comment: it's related but not exactly the same (see my last remark in question)