# Classification of all matrix transformations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry

What is a complete exhaustive classification of all geometric transforms on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane obtained with:

1. 2x2 matrices$$A = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$$ applied to a point $X= (x, y)$.
2. 3x3 matrices $$A = \pmatrix{a & b& c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i}$$  applied to a point $(x, y)$ noted $X = (x, y, 1)$ using homogeneous coordinates.

?

Note:

- I've already looked at [Transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) Wikipedia page, which is good, but it mainly gives examples (stretching, squeezing, etc.), and doesn't state it as a *full classification of all possible* transforms.
- In most lecture notes / resources I find, it usually goes this way:

  > here is a list of geometric transforms => here are their representation as matrix

  In this question I'm more looking for:

  > here is a random 3x3 matrix => what geometric transform is it?

I'm looking for an exhaustive classification like *"All 2x2 matrices can be either a rotation matrix with parameter $\theta$, a scaling matrix of parameter $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, a blahblah matrix of parameter $\delta$, or a composition of any 2 of them"* (nonsense, just an example).

Comment: What do you mean "classification"?  You mean "a finite list of random types of transformations which I can sort all these matrices into"?

Comment: @rschwieb A finite list of transformations (e.g. rotation $R_\theta$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, + ... + ...), such that any transformation can be expressed as either one of them or composition of them

Comment: OK: the question you're asking in the second yellow box is not fruitful, but your version of it in this last comment is reasonable.  I think you should replace that yellow box with the comment you just wrote.

Comment: There are many possible elementary decompositions. You need to be more specific about what you want. In some respects, all linear operators on $\mathbb R^2$ are the same type, as they transform the unit circle into a (possibly degenerate) ellipse.

Comment: @Bungo I'm looking for a classification like *"All 2x2 matrices can be either a rotation matrix with parameter $\theta$, a scaling matrix of parameter $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, a blahblah matrix of parameter $\delta$, or a composition of any 2 of them"*. Something like that...

Comment: @Basj Are you only interested in transformations that are invertible?

Comment: @rschwieb Possibly all of them, but it's ok for only invertible one first.

Comment: How about: all $2\times 2$ matrices can be decomposed as the product of an orthogonal matrix (rotation and/or reflection), followed by a diagonal matrix (stretch or shrink the canonical axes), followed by another orthogonal matrix"? This is essentially the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition)

Comment: This might be it for 2x2 matrices, so are there no other corner cases for 2x2 matrices that are not covered by rotation + scaling on both axes + rotation?

Comment: Also @Bungo what would it be for 3x3 matrices applied on 2D plane using homogeneous coordinates?

Comment: @Basj Rotation and/or scaling, meaning that some of the axes may be inverted/flipped in the opposite direction. That does indeed cover all cases, i.e. all real matrices (even non-square matrices) can be decomposed in this way. Complex matrices can also be decomposed this way if we substitute unitary matrices in place of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you @Bungo. If you have a few minutes, could you post it as an answer for the case 1. mentioned in the question? (with these details about "rotation and reflection" vs "rotation or reflection" , etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer, that helps to see the big picture of the classification of (nonsingular) transformations ([source](https://ags.cs.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/inf_ags/3dcv-ws11-12/3DCV_WS11-12_lec04.pdf), page 12-16):

[image]

Note:

- the "Projective transformation" here is equivalent to the terminology ["Homography"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography)
- "Euclidean" here seems to mean an [Euclidean plane isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry). [It can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Euclidean_plane_isometry) that there are **four types** of Euclidean plane isometries:

  - rotations
  - reflection (mirror with a reflection axis)
  - translations
  - reflection followed by a translation (known as "glide reflection")

Comment: Why have you limited this list to nonsingular transformations?