# Projective Transformation between two matched 3D point sets

Tags: linear-transformations, 3d, nonlinear-optimization, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

I have two point sets of about 800 3D-points that are matched. That means, I know the corresponding points in the two point clouds.
Now I want to minimize the distance between the corresponding points using a projective transformation because I know that the transformation can't be completly described by an affine transformation. So after using an affine transformation I still have an error that is a little too high.

Now my question is how I can compute a viable projective transformation that maps the points of one set to the points of the other set? I know how to calculate least square estimates of a rigid transformation and of an affine transformation but I can't find any sources how to handle two large point sets and compute something like a least squares solution of a projective transform. Is that possible?

At the moment my idea is the following:
1. Compute an affine transformation, using the least squares solution of:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
x'  \\
y' \\
z'  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y \\
z  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$

This matrix is used as an start vector for a minimization procedure using levenberg-marquardt on the following matrix:

$
T =
 \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$

The idea is to minimize the cost function of the reprojection error:

$
\sum \| T\cdot x_i - x_i' \| 
$

The problem in my eyes is that I don't use a parametrization of the matrix that preserves non singularity in the optimization process which could be a problem because projective transformation matrices have to be non singular and in addition I thought that I don't need a non-linear optimization routine (because the projective transformation is still linear)!
Do you think this approach is viable or is there any better and easier way to determine a projective transformation between two 3D-point sets?

Actually I know that I only have to solve the following equation system:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
wx'  \\
wy' \\
wz'  \\
w
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x  \\
y \\
z  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$
So the difference to the affine transformations are the homogeneous coordinates. But how is this possible in a sense of regarding 800 points in a least squares way?

Best regards!

Comment: You might find some leads in the answers to question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2789094/1257