# Proving that a transformation is an isometry and find the projectivity which reperesents

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projective-geometry, projective-space

Consider the transformation:

$T
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$  $\mapsto$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x+y-1 \\
    -x+y+1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

*Show that $T$ is an isometry, then write the matrix of the projectivity $\tau:\mathbb{P^2} \to \mathbb{P^2} $ where $\mathbb{P^2} = P(\mathbb{R^3})$. Write also $\tau^{-1}$.*

To answer to the first question I think I have just to show that it has been obtained as composition of projectivities of the form: $z \mapsto az$ and $z \mapsto z+b$

For the second one, should I find a projective frame for the input and one other for the output? Such as:

$P_1
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $P_2
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $P_3
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $P_4
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ and $Q_1
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    0 \\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $Q_2
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $Q_3
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    0 \\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $Q_4
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\\sqrt{2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Where

$Q_1 \in x+y-1$;

$Q_2 \in x+y-1 \cap -x+y+1$

$Q_3 \in -x+y+1$

$Q_4 = Q_1+Q_2+Q_3$

So, the matrix which represents $\tau$ would be: \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0 \\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\sqrt{2}
    \end{bmatrix}

Am I right? What about $\tau^{-1}$? Thank you everyone

Comment: Asking you to write *the* matrix of the transformation is a bit misleading. The matrix is homogeneous, so any nonzero scalar multiple of it also represents $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the transformation is an isometry, you might be best served demonstrating that it preserves length. So if you have two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and compute the distance between them, and then do the same for the transformed points, the distances should match. You can actually avoid a few square roots, and all the hassle that goes with them, by comparing squared distances instead. So show that the following equality always holds:

\begin{align*}
(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2&=
\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2(x_1+y_1-1)-\frac{\sqrt2}2(x_2+y_2-1)\right)^2
\\&+
\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2(-x_1+y_1+1)-\frac{\sqrt2}2(-x_2+y_2+1)\right)^2
\end{align*}

You *can* show that a transformation is an isometry by decomposing it into more elementary isometries like translation, rotation or reflection. But I'd guess the naïve approach I just suggested is easier in most cases to most readers. And the $z\mapsto az$ you mentioned sounds like it might have a scaling component you don't want in an isometry, so that only would make sense if you identify vectors with complex numbers, require $\lvert a\rvert=1$ and are OK with not covering reflections.

To turn the operation into a transformation matrix, I must say that while I welcome the general [approach of mapping four points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416), I consider it overkill in this scenario. Just start with the general form of the matrix, using the fact that any affine transformation can be written with $0,0,1$ in the last row:

$$\begin{pmatrix}m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\tfrac{\sqrt2}2(x+y-1) \\
\tfrac{\sqrt2}2(-x+y+1) \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now the right hand side is fairly simple: it has one component that is linear in $x$, so put the coefficient of that into the first column. Then there is a component that is linear in $y$, so put the coefficient of that in the second column. And lastly there is a constant term, which goes into the third column. Done. If you want you can pick a convenient scalar multiple of the matrix in the end, e.g. to avoid fractions.

For the inverse operation, just computing the [matrix inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3_%C3%97_3_matrices) would work. Often the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) is even easier to compute since it avoids divisions, and it differs from the inverse only in a common factor which is irrelevant for projective geometry.

Comment: Thank you, really clear and exhaustive!