# How to complete a noisy perspective rectangle?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of a rectangle that is noisy (perspective image).

[image: paper image]

I know the value of $x$, $y$, and angle $3$. Angles "$2$" and "$4$" are not accurate. Also, I know the real rectangle size. The angle "$1$" is noisy. I want to complete the rectangle and calculate the angle "$4$" in the image.

Having this information, can I calculate the angle "$4$" and complete the rectangle?

Comment: When you say "rectangle", do you mean a quadrilateral? Otherwise, knowing x and y means you know everything.

Comment: Yes. I mean perspective rectangle

Answer (score 0):

> Can I calculate the angel "4" and complete the rectangle?

Short answer: **no**.

As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416), a perspective transformation is uniquely defined by four points and their images. So you can take any rectangle as preimage, guess positions 2, 3, 4 from your image, place point 1 anywhere and still find a projective transformation to achieve this mapping. Knowing 2, 3, 4 and the original rectangle does not add value towards knowing where 1 has to be. Assuming perspective rectangle means a rectangle under an arbitrary projective transformation, which is how I'd read the question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to estimate the value of angle $4$ in the following steps:

1. Detect the contour that delimits the rectangle in the image. Since your image has a high contrast, it should be enough to use a [marching squares algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) with a global threshold.
2. Process the contour to split it into 4 contours, one for each edge. You could split, *e.g.*, the contour with the four extreme points (most up-left, most up-right, most down-left, most down-right).
3. For every such contour, estimate the best fitting line, *i.e.*, the line that interpolates the points of the edge contour in a "best" way. For this step you could use a [RANSAC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).
4. Finally, estimate the angle $4$ by computing the angle between the two lines that interpolate the edges incident in angle $4$.