# Prove there's a unique projective transformation that maps four points to four points

Tags: projective-geometry

As the title states, the question is to prove that there's a unique Projective Transformation that maps four points of $\mathbb{R^2}$ to the projective plane. I tried defining the projective transformation as $\bf{x'} $$= M\cdot $$\bf x$ where $M$ is a $3 \times3$ matrix and defining four points $x_i = \pmatrix{a_i\cr b_i}$ but I don't think i'm getting anywhere. Any tips?

Comment: Count degrees of freedom.

Comment: Alternatively, construct the transformation explicitly. One such construction is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/265466). You’ll find that you’ll need to impose some conditions on the points for your proposition to hold.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, a *unique* determination of a collineation is only possible if you have been provided a mapping from one set of four points to another set of four points such that *no three points in either set are collinear*.

One way to do this, similar to your initial approach, is by showing that the determination of the required collineation is equivalent to solving a system of 12 homogeneous linear equations in 13 variables when the rank of the matrix of the coefficients is 12. I've written a detailed writeup of this approach in my [blog](https://blog.immenselyhappy.com/post/pg-sol-5.8/#1) in case you get stuck.