# finding a projective transformation between points

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projection

So I was trying this exercise, but I have a lot of doubts: On a projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{R})$ I have these points: $$P_0=\{0,0,1\},\quad P_1=\{0,1,-1\},\quad P_2=\{1,-1,0\},\quad P_3=\{1,1,-3\}$$and $$Q_0=\{1,0,0\},\quad Q_1=\{1,0,-1\},\quad Q_2=\{0,1,-1\},\quad Q_3=\{0,1,1\}$$
I have to say if exist a projective transformation $f:P^2(\Bbb{R})\rightarrow P^2(\Bbb{R})$ such that

$f(P_j)=Q_j$, $\qquad j=0,1,2,3$

and, If $f$ exist, I have to show it.

So, I defined an arbitrary Matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b &c\\d & e &f\\g & h &i\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I calculate $A*P_0=Q_0$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b &c\\d & e &f\\g & h &i\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

And I find $
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
c=1 \\ 
f=0 \\ 
i=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$

I do the same whit the others:

$A*P_1=Q_1 \Rightarrow$ $
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b-c=1 \\ 
e-f=0 \\ 
h-i=-1
\end{array}
\right. 
$

$A*P_2=Q_2 \Rightarrow$ $
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a-b=0 \\ 
d-e=1 \\ 
g-h=-1
\end{array}
\right. 
$

$A*P_3=Q_3 \Rightarrow$ $
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b-3c=0 \\ 
d+e-3f=1 \\ 
g+h-3i=1
\end{array}
\right. 
$

But I can't find any solution for this system... Does it mean that $f$ doesn't exist?
And when it says "show $f$ explicitly" what does it mean exactly?

Comment: You can’t use strict equality when you’re working with homogeneous matrices. By doing so you’re effectively limiting yourself to an _affine_ transformation, and there is none that performs the desired mapping. So, for instance, your first constraint should be $AP_1=c_1 Q_1$ for some unknown scalar $c_1$. Since you’re working in $\mathbb P^2$ you can avoid introducing these extra unknowns by using cross products, e.g., $Q_1\times AP_1=0$.

Comment: That said, this is basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/265466. See in particular [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/265466).

Comment: I saw that question, but I don't know hot to apply it to my exercise

Comment: For @amd I tried in that way and I found the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 3 &2\\-1 & 0 &0\\0 & -1 &0\end{bmatrix}$, is this possible? And I don't understand: the projective transformation is a matrix?

Comment: Existence is assured by the fundamental theorem of projective geometry. A transformation is not a matrix, although it can be represented by one. Why were you trying to compute this matrix in the first place if not to find $f$ explicitly?