# Perspective warp evaluation as a convex combination of 4 sample points

Tags: projective-geometry

Suppose we know that $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a perspective warp function; that is,
there exist real parameters $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$ such that, for all $(x,y)$:
$$
    F((x,y)) = ((ax + by + c), (dx + ey + f)) / (gx + hy + i).
$$
And suppose we are not given $a,...,i$, but instead we are given
the values of F on the corners of the square:
$$
    F((0,0)) = p_{00} \\
    F((1,0)) = p_{10} \\
    F((0,1)) = p_{10} \\
    F((1,1)) = p_{11}
$$
And assume $p_{00},p_{10},p_{11},p_{01}$ form a convex quadrilateral.

Can we then evaluate $F((x,y))$ for an arbitrary input point $(x,y)$?

[image]

One way to do it is to solve for the 9 parameters $a,...,i$, and then evaluate the resulting explicit formula for $F$ at the desired $(x,y)$.  There are actually only 8 degrees of freedom in $F$, since any scalar multiple
of a given solution $a,...,i$ is also a solution representing the same $F$;
and there 8 scalar equations, so this is a well-constrained system of equations.

[Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript#answer-339033) shows another method
for computing the parameters of $F$.

But is there a more neat and direct geometric method for evaluating $F$ in terms of the sample points $p_{00},p_{10},p_{01},p_{11}$?

Here are a couple of observations that give us the answer easily in some special cases.

Observation #1: Since $F$ preserves straight lines, $F((0.5, 0.5))$ must be the intersection of the two diagonals:
$$
  F((0.5, 0.5)) = \frac{\mathrm{Area}(p_{00},p_{10},p_{01})p_{11} + \mathrm{Area}(p_{11},p_{01},p_{10})p_{00}} {\mathrm{Area}(p_{00},p_{10},p_{11},p_{01})}
$$

Observation #2: If $p_{00},p_{10},p_{11},p_{01}$ happen to form a parallelogram, then $F$ is an affine warp, in which case we can evaluate F at any $(x,y)$ by using bilinear interpolation:
$$
  F((x,y)) = (1-x)(1-y)p_{00} + x(1-y)p_{10} + (1-x)y \;  p_{01} + x \; y \; p_{11}
$$

In general, I expect the answer will be a neat symmetric-looking formula having the flavor of the
above two special cases: that is, an affine combination of the points $p_{00},p_{10},p_{01},p_{11}$, with the coefficients being some expressions involving $x$, $y$, and possibly triangle areas or cross ratios involving the four points.  In particular, when $x,y \in [0,1]$, I expect the formula will naturally be a convex combination of the four points.

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation for this, but the answer seems to be the following.

$F((x,y))$ is a weighted average (affine combination) of $p_{00},p_{10},p_{01},p_{11}$, the respective weights (coefficients) being proportional to:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    (1-x)\;(1-y)&\mathrm{Area}(p_{10},p_{11},p_{01}) \\
    x\;(1-y)&\mathrm{Area}(p_{11},p_{01},p_{00} \\
    (1-x)\;y\;&\mathrm{Area}(p_{00},p_{10},p_{11})
\\    x\;y\;&\mathrm{Area}(p_{01},p_{00},p_{10})
\end{aligned}
$$
In other words, it's bilinear interpolation, with each coefficient scaled by the respective opposite triangle area.

We can, at least, easily check that this answer is plausible:

- it's correct on the corners of the square
- it's correct on $(0.5,0.5)$ (Observation #1)
- it agrees with Observation #2 in the case of a parallelogram (that is, when all four Areas are equal)
- the answer is a convex combination (i.e. all four weights are non-negative) if and only if $x,y \in [0,1]$.