# How do projective transformation matrices work?

Tags: matrices, projection, computer-vision

I've been working on a tool to turn photos of graphs into digital data (I know there are already tools out there, I wanted to understand the mechanism and I find learning by doing the easiest), but I cannot get my head around the maths involved.

I've had a bit of a read and I think I understand the matrix stuff involved in affine transformations, but I seem to be at a bit of a roadblock with projections, which is what I think I need (but could be wrong there too).

I've got the following image and I know the pixel coordinates of the axes (red) and the data that I want to extract (blue). I also, obviously, know the axis limits that I need to transform the data to.

[image: Graph with points displayed]

What I cannot work out at all is how to do that transformation! If anyone has any advice for how to understand how to get from the projected image to an un-projected set of data I would be massively appreciative.

Comment: This does not seem to fit the usual projective geometry scheme of projecting onto a viewing plane (or, in this case, line). I don't see why you expect this to come from a linear model. In any event, perspective projections are not affine transformations. There are lots of books on computer graphics, but I have a very brief discussion of perspective projection matrices on pp. 322-325 of *Linear Algebra: A Geometric Approach*. But, again, I don't see how this applies.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin -  I did say I could be wrong in my question, so thanks for confirming. I'd assumed I'd found the right thing as I thought that straightening up the graph images would be no different to straightening up architectural photos which I believe they use homography for, but I must have not quite understood. Do you have any ideas of where would be a good place to look next?

Comment: I truly do not understand what your image is depicting. I just said it doesn't look like projection in any sense that I can think of (whether linear algebra or projective geometry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered very eloquently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/86932) and so this is the method I've used to solve the problem I'm having, demonstrated below (without the maths).

I've gone from the following projected graph of a known curve that I created, so that I can test my maths:

[image]

With the data points for the axes used to map the transformation of the axes and data:

[image]

I used the transformation matrix between the marked up axes and the axis limits on the image to obtain the marked up data points' "real" values, as compared to a plot of the known curve:

[image]

Obviously the points I've selected might not be dead on so any error is more likely due to that than numerical errors.