# Confirm: 2d transformation matrix cannot change rectangle into isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, matrices

This non-mathematician needs some help...

Given any 2D transformation matrix as typically used in game programming like this:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can anyone confirm that such a matrix cannot be used to convert a rectangle into an isosceles trapezoid?

I don't need a proof, I just need to know it's not possible.

I looked at [2D transformation matrix to make a trapezoid out of a rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/2d-transformation-matrix-to-make-a-trapezoid-out-of-a-rectangle) but I couldn't figure out if the answerers were talking about the typical game 2d matrix or other matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of the matrix you quoted corresponds to an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). One property of these is that they map parallel lines again to parallel lines. So you are right, the two parallel lines of a rectangle (extended beyond the corners to infinite lines) cannot be made to meet, as they would have to for an isosceles trapezoid.